# Word 2010 page numbering different

Tags: microsoft-word

How can we do this in Word?

Leave first 2 pages empty, 
and start numbering from 3rd page with 1 (4th page -2, 5th page -3, etc).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To leave first two pages empty:

- go to page layout - in page setup section select breaks and click section break - next page
- insert a page break at the beginning of your document (CTRL+ENTER)

Insert page number:

- double click on a header in Section 2 (3rd page or later)
- in header & footer tools' design tab:

  - deactivate "link to previous"
  - page number - select the layout you need
  - page number - format page number set "start numbering" to 1

[image]

Comment: Very very helpful. Thanks too much! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

In Word, go to `Insert` tab, then choose `Page Number` -> `Page Number Format`

In here, you can choose the `Start at` under the `Page numbering` section.

HACK: Then, add a white shape with a white border to cover up the page numbers

Comment: no need to add anything, just ctrl+enter to break the page